# allow algorithm and picture to overlap

Tags: minipage, algorithms

I put an algorithm and a picture side by side. I realized that so far by putting them in a minipage environment (algorithm and picture get 0.5\textwidth each)

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{\\ Stress calculation}
\begin{algorithmic}[1] 
\State The first line of an longer algorithm
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\def\svgwidth{300pt}
\input{./example.pdf_tex}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The file example.pdf_tex is a picture generated by Inkscape:

```
%%
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \newcommand*\fsize{\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}%
  \newcommand*\lineheight[1]{\fontsize{\fsize}{#1\fsize}\selectfont}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{156.0915483bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.81532061)%
    \lineheight{1}%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{example.pdf}}%
    \put(1,0.31527883){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l} \end{tabular}}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

I would like to draw a line between the algorithm and the picture, but the minipage environment does not allow to leave the 0.5\textwidth section of the picture (if I draw the line in inkscape).

How can I do that?

Comment: Unse tikzmark to locate places in text (algorithm comment?) and tikz [remember picture,overlay] to draw the arrows.  You might put the image inside a tikz node [inner sep=0pt] to get coordinates.

Comment: I can draw arrows with tikzmark as a comment in the algorithm environment, but the issue is the same: the minipage environment forces all algorithm components to stay within in the 0.5\textwidth section. I guess the minipage environment is not pertinent as to what I want to do.

Comment: Without a Minimal Working Example I can't really tell what the relationship is between your minipages, image and tikzpicture.  A tkizpicture in overlay takes up no space but can draw anyhwere on the page.

Comment: @John I added a minimal working example to my question. I would appreciated your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm environment is a float and you can't put floats inside minipages. You **can** use paracol.

I added tikzmarks inside the algorithm and inside the picture environment, then connected them with arrows.  It takes two runs.

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{\\ Stress calculation}
\begin{algorithmic}[1] 
\State The first line of an longer algorithm \tikzmark{A}
\State The second line of an longer algorithm \tikzmark{B}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\switchcolumn

\def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \newcommand*\fsize{\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}%
  \newcommand*\lineheight[1]{\fontsize{\fsize}{#1\fsize}\selectfont}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{156.0915483bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.81532061)%
    \lineheight{1}%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}%
    \put(0,0.81532061) {\tikzmark{C}}% top of picture environment
    \put(0,0) {\tikzmark{D}}% bottom of picture environment
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{example-image}}%
    \put(1,0.31527883){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l} \end{tabular}}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
\end{paracol}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw[red, <-] (pic cs:A) -- (pic cs:C);
\draw[blue, <-] (pic cs:B) -- (pic cs:D);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I did not check it, but the adding the tikzmarks commands and the tikzpicture to my MWE, ie keeping the minipages, would give the same result as your code, right?

Comment: If putting a float inside a minipage worked, yes.